# TravisCI Allow failures at Intersection of Two Elements

Tags: travis-ci

With Travis CI I can allow failures for languages like Ruby 1.8.7:

```
matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - rvm: 1.8.7
```

And I can allow failures for certain environment variables

```
matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - env: "RAILS_VERSION=master"
```

What I want to do is allow failures for an intersection of environment variable and Ruby version. Like

```
matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - env: "RAILS_VERSION=master" && rvm: 1.8.7
```

Is it possible to do this with travis?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - env: "RAILS_VERSION=master"
      rvm: 1.8.7
```